# The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart' or a test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using ChangeNotifier and i change their value and notify like below,

```
// Declare
ValueNotifier<bool> isDisplay = new ValueNotifier(false);

// Change value
isDisplay.value = false;
isDisplay.notifyListeners();
```

It's working fine. but it's raise warning like below,
[image]

Can we resolve this using proper implementation or other things ?

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L309 - this is the implementation of `ValueNotifier.value` setter

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: I'm seeing this warning when using a plain ChangeNotifier too, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was getting these errors too, more specifically, those 2:

```dart
The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart'.dart(invalid_use_of_protected_member)
The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart' or a test.dart(invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member)
```

After a bit of research, I've come to some conclusions and a solution. Thought I should share it with people who encounter this problem.

### The problem

What it says actually is quite obvious, “If you wanna call `notifyListeners()`, you have to do it in a subclass of ChangeNotifier or in a test file”

“But why is that?” Understandably, this was my second question. But before that, a little bit about where the heck that notifyListeners method is coming from

### notifyListeners method

If you look at the implementation of ValueNotifier, it extends ChangeNotifier class:

> [image: ValueNotifier class]

and ChangeNotifier has a `notifyListeners()` method (which is why, in the first place, we can use this method) but not in a usual way:

> [image: notifyListeners method of ChangeNotifier]

It's protected.

### @protected annotation in Dart | [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/protected-constant.html)

> [`@protected` annotation] Indicates that the annotated instance member (method, getter, setter, operator, or field) m in a class or mixin C should only be referenced in specific locations.
>
> A **reference from within the library** in which C is declared is valid. Additionally, a **reference from within an instance member in C**, or **a class that extends, implements, or mixes in C** (either directly or indirectly), or **a mixin that uses C as a superclass constraint** is valid. Additionally, a **reference from within an instance member in an extension that applies to C** is valid.”

In a more worldly explanation: it can be used in subclasses that **directly extends** (or mixins) the `ChangeNotifier` class or in test files. Since you want to use it in your logic code, you have to do the first section in this paragraph: “extend or mixin ChangeNotifier where you want to call `notifyListeners` method.”

### Where to extend (or mixin) the ChangeNotifier class?

You may be tempted to use it in your Stateful or Stateless Widget, and, since Dart is single-inheritance, you'd have to “mixin” the ChangeNotifier class to your class, but you'd be wrong.

##### 1. Why you must not mixin to StatefulWidget

ChangeNotifier class defines its own `dispose` method. And since **the class or mixin that mixins to your class** supersedes the previous inherited methods, by looking at the methods of ChangeNotifier, you'll notice the `dispose` method (which is used to remove the listeners). So, if you mix ChangeNotifier to StatefulWidget, now your `dispose` would be ChangeNotifier's `dispose` rather than the State's `dispose`.

Remember, you have to release the resources used by State class no matter what. Normally, if you do not override the `dispose` method in your State, the framework does this for you and releases the resources by itself, which is cool; but since you just changed the dispose method's ancestor, framework will not trigger the required dispose method. And that **will raise a runtime error**.

##### 2. Why you must not mixin to StatelessWidget

And on the StatelessWidget's case, now your widget would have an instance variable `_listener` that's **not final** which comes from the mixed ChangeNotifier. So, you couldn't define a const constructor, which is the most important part of a StatelessWidget (talking about widget rebuild and performance-related situations).

### What to do?

In the end, a solution to this would be, to create a new class to manipulate value changes and **extend or mixin** ChangeNotifier to this class. Then you can call `notifyListeners()` method wherever and whenever you like! (but of course, don't call notifyListeners **unless you use complex objects or send the same value**)

Also, these classes are preferably called as 'Controller', 'ViewModel', 'BLoC', or any other name to state that they're mutating/controlling your values and trigger UI to rebuild when needed. (Which what you should do in the first place: separate your UI from your Logic layer).

### Further readings

- [State management for minimalists](https://suragch.medium.com/flutter-state-management-for-minimalists-4c71a2f2f0c1)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call `notifyListeners`, as this is automatically called when a new value is set.

`ChangeNotifier` implementations like `ValueListener` should never require `notifyListeners` to be called manually.

Comment: Maybe when you are playing with ValueNotifier<List>, don't you need it?

Comment: @Ataberk Yes, I agree, to me, it should be an option for complex objects.

Comment: @MarwinLebensky You can use `Equatable` or override `operator ==` to avoid using notifyListeners. I didn't know this back then.

Comment: @Ataberk Hey, could you provide a minimal example or a resource about the last part? When and where to use `Equatable` or override `operator ==` to avoid calling `notifyListeners`? This sounds promising but seems like I'm missing a point on where to place them and how this helps with ChangeNotifier.

Comment: @KHAN Flutter doesn't recommend you yo use `notifyListeners()` outside of `ValueNotifier` class. Create a class with a set of property. Change the object's property, it is the same object for dart. Because dart checks for object's hashCode to for equality. You should override `==` operator for per property. Bitwise XOR per property is a good practice to differ objects. For example pass `title.hashCode ^ content.hashCode ^ price.hashCode` to `==` operator. Now if you change content, price or title, your object is different from past instance. But try to store old object to compare with new one.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Going through to docs after seeing your comment, the first sentence in the `addListener` method is actually `Register a closure to be called when the “object changes”.` So it makes sense to design an object (to which the listener will be added) to be aware of its properties' changes specifically. Also, `hashValues` and `hashList` works for me for now. Thanks for the heads up man!