# Flutter: Getting an error about using notifyListeners in a class that doesn't extend ChangeNotifier, but it seems to work?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-state

I have these two problems reported by vscode 98 times in my project, every time that I use classModelName.notifyListeners to update the state using the provider:

`The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart'.`

`The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart' or a test.`

Initially, I tried extending every relevant class with ChangeNotifier, but I ran into the issue outlined in this github issue, where widgets don't dispose correctly. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24293

So I just removed the class extensions, and the app works perfectly, but the 95 reported problems are back.

Is it something I should be worried about? I'm concerned it might cause issues down the line, or be causing performance issues I'm unaware of etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change\_notifier.dart' or a test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173183/the-member-notifylisteners-can-only-be-used-within-packageflutter-src-founda)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan hey thanks for looking into it - that looks pretty similar to my issue yes. But the solution doesn't help much unfortunately, as I already have other classes that do currently extend Change Notifier and I still get the problem raised.

Comment: To be clear, it's not an issue, it's by design. When a member is marked as protected, it's not meant to accessed from outside. You should modify your code in a way that doesn't violate this rule.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I get that, but my issue is that the only way I currently know how to write it in a way that doesn't violate the rule is to extend change notifier in the necessary classes. But the problem is that then I get issues with the widgets not disposing properly as is mentioned in the github link in my post as well as the post you linked as well.

I would like to not violate the rule, but my current situation is violate = working code, not violated = broken code